# Jetpack navigation: How do I open a new fragment from a recyclerview adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I usually open a new fragment from an existing fragment or activity. However, with an adapter, which can be used in multiple fragments / activities, how do I open a particular fragment dynamically?

I usually use the following piece of code:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_destinationFragment);
```

after creating an  action in the navgraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As navigation occurs among fragments, so normally you'd keep the fragment's the responsibility to do that.

As you told that **adapter which can be used in multiple fragments**, so it should be attached to a particular fragment at a time, which normally it's the fragment that instantiated it.

So, you can pass a listener interface to the adapter which is implemented by the fragment; where you can trigger its callback in the adapter whenever you want to navigate to another fragment in the nav graph.

This callback method will be executed at the fragment which already implements the listener, and you can normally use the traditional navigation code:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_destinationFragment);
```

This way your adapter can be reused, and every time a fragment wants to reuse it, it should implements the listener.

**Note:** Probably you can pass an `int` argument to the listener callback that pass in the row number in the adapter back to the fragment so that you might decide to navigate to some other fragment.

This way you can keep the navigation only through fragments.